# Regex for substring matching with space and substitution

Tags: r, regex, string, string-matching

I want to combine words in one string having spaces in between, which are similar to words in another string without spaces in between them (In R).
eg

> s1 = 'this is an example of an undivided string case here'
>
> s2 = 'Please note th is is an un di vid ed case right he r e for you!'

s2 needs to be converted into

> s2 =  'Please note this is an undivided case right here for you!'

based on combined words in s1 which are same as non combined successive/continuous words in s2(with spaces in between)

I am new to R and tried with gsub, and different combinations of '\s', but not able to get the desired result.

Comment: It looks like `NLP` problem. Related to `spell check problem`.

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve what you need by

- removing all whitespaces from the string you want to search for (`s1`) (with `gsub("\\s+", "", x)`), then
- insert whitespace patterns (`\s*`) in between each char (use something like `sapply(strsplit(unspace(s1), ""), paste, collapse="\\s*")`), and then
- replace all the matches with the replacement with `gsub(pattern, s1, s2)`.

See the [**R demo**](https://ideone.com/E5eZ9M):

```
s2 = 'Please note th is is an un di vid ed case right he r e for you!'
s1 = 'this is an undivided case right here'
unspace <- function(x) { gsub("\\s+", "", x) }
pattern <- sapply(strsplit(unspace(s1), ""), paste, collapse="\\s*")
gsub(pattern, s1, s2)
## => [1] "Please note this is an undivided case right here for you!"
```

Comment: This would work fine, if a complete, continuous string(w/o space) is to be find in another string(with or w/o space). But wouldn't work in case of comparison required for individual words(and not a complete string). Updated the example in Question to make it more clear.

Comment: That is not that easy, but I will see what I can do later.